# Tag Proposal: [Interactive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm proposing a new tag named [interactive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive) for challenges that go beyond simple stdin/stdout processing. This would be challenges that require the program to respond to user input in some fashion, interactively.

- [The shortest distance between two points is a line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146809)
- [Create a Checkbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109155/42963)
- [Create a Paint program!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/117162/42963)
- [Type the Alphabet - as fast as you can!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/146587/42963)
- [Implement a Stopwatch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/108468/42963)

Etc.

Answer (score 36):

### Yes, this should be a tag

It checks off the 3 criteria I believe are important for new tags:

1. It concerns a quality not covered by other tags.
2. It is a useful quality that users would want to seek out (or avoid).
3. It has a meaningful name.